# Find out a GIT link to a folder

Tags: git, github

I performed following commands in a folder X:

```
git init 
git add . git 
commit -m "initial"
```

From what I understand about git, I suppose I should be able to get some sort of a copy of folder X from, say, another computer. Ho do I get the adress of the folder X? How can I get my folder X from Git using my other computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git isn't a Dropbox :-)

When you initialize a repository on your computer, it is self contained and not published anywhere. To do so, you have different options, one of the simplest is to create a GitHub repo and push your repo to it. It will be then accessible from GitHub, and if you set it as public you can get the URL of any file tracked by Git, provided that you push your commits.

- [Create a GitHub repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)
- Add it as a remote and push (section 3 of the above page)

Comment: Thanks a lot CharlesB :) I had a gut feeling that I was doing something wroong. Again :)